# How do you show a specific label on a post?

Tags: tags, blogger

I currently have the code below (from a blogger template) which seems to randomize the label on each post that pops out on my blog. How do I enforce that I only want to show 1 of these 4 labels only: san francisco, los angeles, chicago, new york. Each blog has one of these labels.

```xml
<div class='postags'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
      <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
      <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'/>
    </b:loop>
  </b:if>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show only one label you can use `limit`, but you can't specify which one that appears

```xml
<div class='postags'>
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels limit 1' var='label'>
      <a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
    </b:loop>
  </b:if>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks. how can I show either first tag or last tag?